# What is the data type we can use in Mongodb for Timestamp in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, php-mongodb

For my one of project, I have to convert a mysql database into Mongodb.But i confused with what i can use the data type instead of  Timestamp data type in Mysql.please can i get to know, what is the data type i can use for mongodb.(I'm creating Mongodb by using php).

Answer (score 1):

[`Date`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-bson-type-date) will be the most appropriate

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of
>   milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). The official BSON
>   specification refers to the BSON Date type as the UTC datetime.

You can get number of seconds from Epoch in MySQL using

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourTimeStampColumn) AS secondsFromEopch FROM yourTable;
```

You don't need to care about timezones here, because MySQL TIMESTAMP is always internally stored as UTC. You can then use this value in PHP to create a [`MongoDate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) object, which you will use to create a BSON document.

```
$mongoDate = new MongoDate($secondsFromEpoch);
```

Comment: Thanks.But there are some values like 2012-03-02,02-59-28. But how can i insert these kind of values ?